# Conditional Logic dynamically

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I search for reusable tool or algorithm that enable me to apply conditional logic to questions dynamically.

lets explain in details:

question 1 - What is your age?

```
a) less 18        
b)between 18-25     
c) greater than 25
```

if he choose

```
a) then he go to Question 2 
b) he will goto question 5 
c) he will goto question 7
```

So as I said the next question depends on the answer of the current question.I don't need to set if condition for each question .I need it to be dynamically.

I hope it is clear now . Is there any component or design pattern or algorithm implements what I said

All ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you probably want a lookup table, effectively mapping the pair (input question, answer) to the next question number to ask. Perhaps it should default to "go to the next question" if there's no entry in the table.

Exactly how you represent it in data structures will depend on what you're using to store the questions. For example, in SQL you could have a table with columns of "input question, answer, next question". In C# you might have a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>`... or possibly (if there aren't going to be *huge* numbers of questions) just a `List<AnswerPath>` where `AnswerPath` contains the same three values as the SQL table would have done. (Change the name, it's awful, but you get the idea.)

Comment: The problem with this is each question can only ever depend on a single input (question, answer pair).

Comment: What I mean is, when determining the next question, you would look it up based only on two pieces of information: the current question and the selected answer. What if the applicability of the next question depends on the results of several previous questions? Granted, you could do it this way, but it may result in a lot of duplication if the same question can exist at two different points in the tree.

Comment: @chaiguy: *If* the applicability of the question depends on many things, then you change the design. My design copes with exactly what's been requested, and nothing else. ("the next question depends on the answer of the current question")

Comment: Yes, but it's also not very extensible is it? Why limit yourself right off the bat? You might not need questions to depend on multiple previous results right *now*, but to assume that you never will would be silly, especially if this is intended to be a reusable solution. Just my $.02.

Comment: @chaiguy: Because it's simpler. I favour a simple solution for what I need *now* over a complex solution for what I *may* need. I find it's very difficult to accurately predict what you *will* need ahead of time... obviously if you have a use case in mind already, it's worth giving some weight to that - but we have **no** indication here that anything more complex will ever be involved.

Comment: @chaiguy, you have a point, but what if you ain't gonna need it?  why not do the simplest thing that will work?  you could end up with a more complicated design for no real payoff.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you consider complicated. I don't personally find my solution complicated at all (the prerequisites idea, that is--scratch the graph idea that was just a first thought). But I can see where you guys are coming from, and I can definitely appreciate keeping things simple, when it's called for.

Comment: @chaiguy: I think I could code up my idea in about 5 minutes, and spend another 5 minutes adding tests. I suspect you couldn't do the same thing with your idea - partly because there'd be so many more situations which required testing...

Comment: @Jon: I don't think it would take me much longer to implement my system, but I'm not about to unless someone actually wants it for practical purposes. I've spent enough time goofing around already, time to get down to some real work. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Consider building your questions as a graph, where each answer points to an ordered set of other questions.

Even better, give each question a set of prerequisites that must be satisfied by previous answers. For example, for question 2, the prerequisites might be that the answer to question 1 was either a or b.

Then when determining the next question, you would just iterate through each of them until you find the next one whose prerequisites are met.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property called `Next Question` for every answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `Dictionary<Tuple<Question,Answer>>,Question>` so that the question and answer became the key for the next question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern...